# XML nodes into one row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an xml file, and I have to put it's values into one row in SQL. 
I am new in SQL and I couldn't find any solution.

**My XML file is:**

```
<Images xmlns="http://schemas.abc.com/2012/09/Image" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Image>
          <Type>3</Type>
          <Code>928</Code>
     </Image>
     <Image>
          <Type>3</Type>
          <Code>925</Code>
     </Image>
     <Image>
          <Type>4</Type>
          <Code>925</Code>
     </Image>
</Images>
```

**I can query it**

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\abc.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as b;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.abc.com/2012/09/Image')
SELECT 
    im.value('(Type)[1]','int') AS 'ImageType', 
    im.value('(Code)[1]','int') AS 'ImageCode'
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Images/Image') AS X(im);
```

**and I get a result**

```
 ImageType     ImageCode                                      
 -----------------------                                        
   3             928
   3             925
   4             925
```

**but I would like to get like**

```
Image1Type   Image1Code  Image2Type  Image2Code   Image3Type  Image3Code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3           928         3         925            4            925
```

How can I achieve this?

Many Thanks,

Comment: You might like that, but you shouldn't. The first option is a more normalised data structure, and is better and easier to use. Imagine writing the SQL to search for any item with an image code 925.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to give back this data to an application which has some limitation and cannot handle my version. It can handle only one row as a result so that why I need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    i.value('(Image[1]/Type)[1]','int') as Image1Type, 
    i.value('(Image[1]/Code)[1]','int') as Image1Code,
    i.value('(Image[2]/Type)[1]','int') as Image2Type, 
    i.value('(Image[2]/Code)[1]','int') as Image2Code,
    i.value('(Image[3]/Type)[1]','int') as Image3Type, 
    i.value('(Image[3]/Code)[1]','int') as Image3Code
from 
    @xml.nodes('/Images') x(i)
```

Obviously, this doesn't scale for more images, but that's part of the problem with de-normalised data

Comment: Thanks podiluska. That's what I need. It seems first I need to count the nodes put it into a variable then use a loop to populate Image[VARIABLE]/... Do you think it is doable and how can I do this?